# Why is Jena tdb2.tdbquery optimization stuck on "Reorder/generic"

Tags: query-optimization, jena, tdb

I am using apache-jena-4.5.0 and fuseki pretty much out-of-the-box.  I had created a TDB2 dataset using fuseki, but now shut it off and using command-line utilities of jena on a Windows box inside a bash shell.

My basic command is:

`java -cp "*" tdb2.tdbquery --loc ~/path/to/databases/DEMO--explain --set arq:logExec=FINE --time --query ~/path/to/demoquery.txt`

And my question is why does the output always contain only **Reorder/generic** like this:

`15:56:00 INFO  exec            :: Reorder/generic`

Even after I have tried all these:

- successfully run tdb2.tdbstats and gotten a reasonable-looking temp.opt file as output
- moved that temp.opt to each of /path/to/DEMO/stats.opt  and  /path/to/DEMO/Data-001/stats.opt
- tried uppercase STATS.OPT for each since I'm on windows, just to be sure

Still I don't seem to be able to produce any output with **Reorder/stats**

Comment: Try `--set arq:logExec=INFO`

Comment: Still says ```INFO  exec            :: Reorder/generic```   I don't think changing the logging level will change the optimization strategy.   But on the other hand, I'm clearly way off base so I welcome any help.

Comment: Changing the output level should change output : "my question is why does the output always contain only Reorder/generic like this:" . Most output is at INFO including the runtime rewriting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question did not contain enough detail to answer.  The intended question was `why won't TDB2 optimize my query` and the answer was in the SPARQL, not in the invocation of **tdb2.tdbquery** or the location of the **stats.opt** file.

My SPARQL contained multiple **FROM** clauses, which forced TDB into BGP mode (instead of quads) and thwarted any optimization.   As best we can tell at the moment, one wishing to use the TDB2 optimizer should use either the default graph, or a combination of **FROM NAMED** and **GRAPH** which causes the evaluation of graphs one at a time.